# Any one please describe the use of NO_ENTITY_BODY

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I need to know the exact use of NO_ENTITY_BODY.Explanation with example could be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

For GET and DELETE API calls, this property is set in the message context by default. This is used for internal purposes.

In case you want to send a response from ESB to such a request, you need to remove this property. Otherwise, the response body of the message is also ignored and an empty response is sent back to the client.

Comment: could you explain in  detail with example

Comment: what kind of details are you looking for? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want know the exact difference occurs while using NO_ENTITY_BODY. I  tried practically but i am not able to understand.could you help me?.

Comment: Add a <payloadfactory>, NO_ENTITY_BODY and <Respond> mediator in the inflow and see if the client gets the response body you set.